# How to return control to the parent after runing few sub-processes, without waiting for them to exit()?

Tags: c, thread-safety

I am trying to create a tree of processes structured in two dimensions. Actually there will only be processes extending to the right and to the bottom from the parent. So the array like this:

```
tree[0] = tree[1] = 2;
tree[2] = 4;
tree[3] = 1;
```

May produce this structure:

```
process_tree───process_tree───process_tree
           |───process_tree───process_tree
           |───process_tree───process_tree───process_tree───process_tree
           |───process_tree
```

My problem actually is that any time I create an branch of processes, program does not return origin parents PID. Please read `ppid` as "origin parents id", and consider that after running the code bellow the program get stuck at `while (getpid() != ppid)` forever (`spawn()` just creates and branch of processes)

```
while (branch < YDEPTH) {
  printf ("PARENT %d: Hey Kid!\n", getpid());
  spawn(tree[branch], ppid);
  ++ branch;
  while (getpid() != ppid)
    load();   
}
```

On the trace, it is clear that pid stays the same as the last process

```css
PARENT 8585: Hey Kid!
FALL 8585: My parent's PID = 13617
Z CHILD 8586: My parent's PID = 8585
FALL 8586: My parent's PID = 8585
Z CHILD 8587: My parent's PID = 8586
Out to Y dimension from 8587
Out to Y dimension from 8587
Wait for parent (8587/8585)[\]
```

If someone may be interested how exactly `spawn()` works, I posted the code here: https://paste.debian.net/1028623/. Yes, I know I am not using `ppid` in there, been using it for some tests :).

Comment: Note that the `else if (pid == -1)` code will never be executed because the prior `if (pid)` will spot `pid == -1` too.  Either test for failure before testing for being the parent, or drop the irrelevant test.

Comment: Each child process from the first line comes back to launch processes in the second call to `fireUpTheLine()`.  This would lead to confusion.  You need to work harder on determining which processes can return to the `main()`.  You should probably also loop on `wait()` — your original process will have at least two children.

Comment: Also, the argument `pid` to `fireUpTheLine()` is weird.  You always pass 0 from `main()`; inside the function, you simply overwrite the value with the call to `fork()`.  It should be a local variable to the function and nothing should be passed from `main()`.

Comment: However, with all that said, it isn't very clear what you really want to happen.  Do you expect the horizontal lines of dashes to appear?  You don't seem to print any.  Why don't you just iterate of the columns of the `tree` array?  Why is a 2D array with leading dimension `1` (so the only valid subscript is `0`)?  The second dimension doesn't seem to be relevant to your problem.

Comment: I am actually looking for a solution how to determine when the parent takes the control and then return to the `main()` to fire up new line of processes from the parent. I rewrite this code to an recurrent form and try to check if  `getpid()` is an positive number, but that fails.

Comment: I do not understand why wen I try this the fork() in `spawnInRow(int *n)` function returns so often -1, code comes to `printf("Fork error!");` and some processes get quit by the `exit()` at the end of the function.

Comment: The clarity of your question is not improving.  The first version was at least an MCVE ([MCVE]) or very close to one.  What there is here now is fragmentary and difficult to understand.  It still isn't clear what you want, and how you want the printout to appear.  I've not rolled back to an earlier edition, but it is tempting to do so.  It would probably have been clearer if, instead of removing the paragraph of code I commented on in my first comment, you had simply moved it first.  _[…to be continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ My understanding of your code is to have a vector with N values in it. In the original code, you had a pseudo-2D array `tree[1][4]` (which is pseudo-2D because the only valid leading subscript is 0, which isn't very exciting).  And to process the `tree[0][0]` row containing value 3, you want the parent process to fork a child, C1, which will identify itself and fork child C2, which will identify itself and fork child C3, which will identify itself and exit (because only 3 children are wanted), so C2 can exit, so C1 can exit, so the parent can do the next row. Is that right?

Comment: I don't really want to print anything, just create an process structure like i posted now.

Comment: I hope that's more clear now.. sorry, I just stat learning C and IPC.

Comment: If you don't print anything, how on earth are you going to know whether it did the job properly?  You need to be printing abundantly!  Super-abundantly!

Comment: Well, I do print pids and track that by htop or pstree. I mean only that my goal is to make those threads work dynamic based on the array values. I figure out as well that the second index in the array didn't really make sens, so I work at one index array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of what I think you are after — with copious printing that shows me that the code is doing what I expect.  I use some error reporting code of mine that helps immensely by having options to print time and process ID on each message.  This code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void wait_for_kids(void);
static void random_nanosleep(void);

static void process_tree(int row_num, int num_kids)
{
    int i;
    int ppid = getpid();
    err_remark("Launching row %d (%d kids)\n", row_num, num_kids);
    for (i = 0; i < num_kids; i++)
    {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
            err_syserr("Failed to fork: ");
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            err_remark("Child %d at work (parent %d)\n", i + 1, (int)getppid());
        }
        else
        {
            err_remark("Child %d launched (PID %d)\n", i + 1, pid);
            break;
        }
    }
    wait_for_kids();
    if (getpid() != ppid)
    {
        random_nanosleep();
        int status = 10 * row_num + i + 1;
        err_report(ERR_EXIT | ERR_PID | ERR_MILLI | ERR_NOARG0, status,
                   "Process complete (status %d = 0x%.2X)\n", status, status);
    }
    err_remark("Launching of row %d complete\n", row_num);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    err_setlogopts(ERR_PID | ERR_MILLI | ERR_NOARG0);
    if (argc != 1)
        err_usage("");

    int proc_tree[] = { 3, 2, 4, 2 };
    enum { NUM_ROWS = sizeof(proc_tree) / sizeof(proc_tree[0]) };

    err_remark("At work!\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
        process_tree(i + 1, proc_tree[i]);

    err_remark("All done!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void wait_for_kids(void)
{
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
        err_remark("Child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);
    err_remark("No progeny left - woe is me!\n");
}

static void random_nanosleep(void)
{
    srand(getpid());    /* Not very good, but adequate */
    struct timespec nap = { .tv_sec = 0, .tv_nsec = (rand() % 5000 + 5000) * 10000 };
    nanosleep(&nap, 0);
}
```

The main operational code is in `main()` and `process_tree()`; the other two functions declared at the top are utility functions that do a useful job but aren't a major part of the answer.

The code in `process_tree()` deals with one row of the array, and is told the row number (for reporting purposes) and the number of children.  It reports the basic information about what it will do, then launches a `for` loop very similar to yours.  The process forks; if the fork fails, it reports the problem (including the system error message) and exits.  If it is the child, it says that it is at work and who its parent is, and goes around to the next iteration of the loop.  If it is the parent, it notes which child it launched and exits the loop.  At the end of the loop, the process (whether it is the original or one of the child processes) waits for its children to die, and then, if it is not the original process, takes a random nap, and exits with a non-zero status (and a printed message).  If it is the parent (original) process, it says it's done with the current row and returns.

The code in `main()` is basically simple.  It does minimal argument handling and configures the error reporting system so that messages will not include the program name (`ERR_NOARG0`) but will include time with milliseconds (`ERR_MILLI`) and PID (`ERR_PID`), and reports that it is working.  Then, for each row in the tree, it invokes `process_tree()`.  then it reports 'all done' and exits.

The `wait_for_kids()` function simply waits for child processes to die, and reports the status of each child that does die, then proclaims its childless state and returns.

The `random_nanosleep()` code initializes the random number generator separately for each process so that it sleeps for a different time, which is configured to be between 50 and 100 milliseconds.  (Without that, the whole process takes a matter of maybe 20 milliseconds.)

An example run:

```
2018-06-09 14:23:15.717 - pid=29868: At work!
2018-06-09 14:23:15.718 - pid=29868: Launching row 1 (3 kids)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.718 - pid=29868: Child 1 launched (PID 29869)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.718 - pid=29869: Child 1 at work (parent 29868)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.719 - pid=29869: Child 2 launched (PID 29870)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.719 - pid=29870: Child 2 at work (parent 29869)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.720 - pid=29870: Child 3 launched (PID 29871)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.720 - pid=29871: Child 3 at work (parent 29870)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.720 - pid=29871: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:15.790 - pid=29871: Process complete (status 14 = 0x0E)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.790 - pid=29870: Child 29871 exited with status 0x0E00
2018-06-09 14:23:15.791 - pid=29870: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:15.843 - pid=29870: Process complete (status 13 = 0x0D)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.844 - pid=29869: Child 29870 exited with status 0x0D00
2018-06-09 14:23:15.844 - pid=29869: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:15.927 - pid=29869: Process complete (status 12 = 0x0C)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.928 - pid=29868: Child 29869 exited with status 0x0C00
2018-06-09 14:23:15.928 - pid=29868: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:15.928 - pid=29868: Launching of row 1 complete
2018-06-09 14:23:15.928 - pid=29868: Launching row 2 (2 kids)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.929 - pid=29868: Child 1 launched (PID 29872)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.929 - pid=29872: Child 1 at work (parent 29868)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.930 - pid=29872: Child 2 launched (PID 29873)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.930 - pid=29873: Child 2 at work (parent 29872)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.931 - pid=29873: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:15.987 - pid=29873: Process complete (status 23 = 0x17)
2018-06-09 14:23:15.988 - pid=29872: Child 29873 exited with status 0x1700
2018-06-09 14:23:15.988 - pid=29872: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.076 - pid=29872: Process complete (status 22 = 0x16)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.076 - pid=29868: Child 29872 exited with status 0x1600
2018-06-09 14:23:16.076 - pid=29868: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.076 - pid=29868: Launching of row 2 complete
2018-06-09 14:23:16.076 - pid=29868: Launching row 3 (4 kids)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.077 - pid=29868: Child 1 launched (PID 29874)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.077 - pid=29874: Child 1 at work (parent 29868)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.078 - pid=29874: Child 2 launched (PID 29875)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.078 - pid=29875: Child 2 at work (parent 29874)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.079 - pid=29875: Child 3 launched (PID 29876)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.079 - pid=29876: Child 3 at work (parent 29875)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.080 - pid=29876: Child 4 launched (PID 29877)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.080 - pid=29877: Child 4 at work (parent 29876)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.080 - pid=29877: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.159 - pid=29877: Process complete (status 35 = 0x23)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.159 - pid=29876: Child 29877 exited with status 0x2300
2018-06-09 14:23:16.160 - pid=29876: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.221 - pid=29876: Process complete (status 34 = 0x22)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.221 - pid=29875: Child 29876 exited with status 0x2200
2018-06-09 14:23:16.222 - pid=29875: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.314 - pid=29875: Process complete (status 33 = 0x21)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.315 - pid=29874: Child 29875 exited with status 0x2100
2018-06-09 14:23:16.315 - pid=29874: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.389 - pid=29874: Process complete (status 32 = 0x20)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.390 - pid=29868: Child 29874 exited with status 0x2000
2018-06-09 14:23:16.390 - pid=29868: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.390 - pid=29868: Launching of row 3 complete
2018-06-09 14:23:16.390 - pid=29868: Launching row 4 (2 kids)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.391 - pid=29868: Child 1 launched (PID 29878)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.391 - pid=29878: Child 1 at work (parent 29868)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.392 - pid=29878: Child 2 launched (PID 29879)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.392 - pid=29879: Child 2 at work (parent 29878)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.393 - pid=29879: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.457 - pid=29879: Process complete (status 43 = 0x2B)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.457 - pid=29878: Child 29879 exited with status 0x2B00
2018-06-09 14:23:16.457 - pid=29878: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.554 - pid=29878: Process complete (status 42 = 0x2A)
2018-06-09 14:23:16.556 - pid=29868: Child 29878 exited with status 0x2A00
2018-06-09 14:23:16.556 - pid=29868: No progeny left - woe is me!
2018-06-09 14:23:16.556 - pid=29868: Launching of row 4 complete
2018-06-09 14:23:16.556 - pid=29868: All done!
```

Comment: Its a great job.. but it still operating on one dimension, not returning to the parent to fire up new branch of processes while letting other branches work at the same time.

Comment: If you want multiple rows working at once, move the `wait_for_kids()` call from `process_tree()` into `main()`, after the loop.  With the sleeping in place, you might well see that working.

Comment: As to working in multiple dimensions, you should specify what you want. The simplest case is two make a 2D array, and have nested loops in `main()` stepping through the 2D array, running `process_tree()` each time.  You need to explain what you want (and have tried) in the question, preferably in the first revision.  You’d probably want to add column number as well as row number to the argument list and the printing.

Comment: (https://paste.debian.net/1028622/) Lets say I have an loop like this in my `main()`. When parent takes control I want to spawn a new branch of processes. The `ppid` is the origin parent's pid. So after the program returns from the `spawn()` and enters `while (getpid() != ppid)`, its gonna loop for ever (because the pid jumps between the last parent and child process from the `spawn()`.. if I understand correctly. So my question is, "How to switch the control back to the parent, so he can take the actions".

Comment: The code in the 'case 0:` is never going to terminate until you signal it (`pid` is private to the process; the process doesn't change it; it never changes).  The double semi-colon is 'legitimate' in that it compiles, but a single semicolon would be sufficient — the null statement between them doesn't help anything (or hinder it, either).  I don't know what you think `spawn()` does — there is a [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) and an extensive set of supporting functions.  And I don't know what `load()` does.  That makes it hard!

Comment: The code from `case 0:` also 'falls through' to the other code, except that the loop does not terminate so it never actually gets there.  And the code shown has zilch to do with a 2D `tree` array.  I'm not trying to be difficult; I'm trying to understand what you are asking about.  But you are not explaining what you are trying to do clearly — possibly because you don't understand what you are supposed to be doing.  Sadly, the only fix for that is talking to the people who set the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your original question is: There is no return of control.  It is not necessary, because the parent never ceeds control to its child - both run in parallel (roughly) and independently ( mostly).

Things they can do:

1. exit itself
2. Try to kill another process
3. exchange data with other processes by  means of [IPC methods](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

You say the immediate problem occurs right in

```
printf ("PARENT %d: Hey Kid!\n", getpid()); spawn(tree[branch], ppid); 
++ branch; while (getpid() != ppid)  load();
```

With the while loop never terminating.

In the loop, you check for the current process pid to be equal to `ppid`. 
Assume that `getpid() != ppid`, so the loop will be entered. Once inside the loop, either the pid of your process or the value of `ppid` would have to change in order to leave the loop again.
The code you provide does not change them directly.  There are 2 possibilities  to ever exit the loop again:

1. `ppid` is a global variable and `load` alters its value.
2. `load` changes the pid of the *current* process.

Regarding point 2: Normally, there is no way for a process to change its pid - thus it would be surprising if the loop once entered *ever* exited again.

What happens inside your `load` function? What do you expect to happens?

Comment: I thought that the program is changing the pid of its processes, as in the swap() output, sometimes pid is in the child process and sometimes loop falls back to the parent process and getpid() returns its value. The load function is just waiting and expecting `getpid()` value to change. I just posted output of the program. So load() executes the statement: `Wait for parent (8587/8585)[\]`

Comment: What do you consider 'your' program'? The operating system only knows processes. If you execute your program, what happens is that a New process with a unique pid is spawned. If this process forks, other processes with their own pids are created. The all run independent of each other (as I said, nearly), and there is no such thing as 'your program', its just a hierarchy of processes, starting at the init process (pid 1).

Comment: I mean OS c:. Any ways, I am trying to understand how to use the IPC to do that.

Comment: Sorry, no insult intended, but it looks to me as if you lacked basic understandment of what processes are and how they work: A process is just a piece of code along with its resources (memory, file descriptors, etc). If you fork, the same code is started a second time, but with all (ok, most) resources copied.

Comment: In fact, each process receives its own virtual address space. If you got 2 processes with to pointers `p` each containing `0x12345678`, the memory address `0x12345678` might contain *different* content in each process, thus `p == 0x12345678` in both processes, but `*p == 1` in process 1 while `*p == 2` in process 2. If you declare a variable in your process like your `ppid`, and then fork, you end up with 2 processes, each with its own `ppid` variable. I don't know what you actually want to achieve, thus I might totally misunderstand you, and if so and you aware of that, ignore my comment.